# dynamically set the size of an array in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Through VBA code, I shall determine the size of one array, say `knownarray()`. The size of this array may be different each time. Depending upon its size, I need to initialize another array of the same size.How should I do that

for eg:

```
knownarray() size = 4
```

so now i need to create an array of size 4 with name say `newarray()`

What I have done so far is something as follows:

```
ReDim NewArray(KnownArray.Size)
```

I know this must be easy but being a novice in VBA i am stuck. Can someone please help me out?

Thanking in advance

Comment: do you mean `Ubound()` when saying `size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim strArr(2 To 4) As String

    strArr(2) = "element1"
    strArr(3) = "element2"


    ReDim anotherArr(LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)) As String

    Debug.Print "the size:" = UBound(anotherArr) - LBound(anotherArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should really account for `LBound` too

Comment: @chrisneilsen appreciate your comment but can you elaborate? Did you mean like `Lbound(strArr) to UBound(strArr)`?

Comment: There is nothing in the OP to say if the original array is or isn't default lower bound.  Should use `ReDim ... LBound to UBound`

Comment: @chrisneilsen oh I agree yes definitely

Answer (score 0):

Another way, especially if you want the values of the first array, is to just make a copy of the existing array:

```
Dim knownArray(2 To 4) As String

Dim copyArr() As String
copyArr() = knownArray()
```

Here `copyArr` is now another different array with the same dimensions *and* the same values. You would only do this if you wanted the values too. If not, the ReDim with bounds answer by @[me how] is the best solution.